# Pycharm Python Path

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having an issue importing a python path into pycharm. I have tried adding the path I want to the following.

Default Settings > Project Interpreters > Interpreter Path

When I do this I see the correct path that I am trying to import from, but when I try to run from the console I still get an import error.

Thanks

Comment: That depends on a number of factors. The easiest way (or  at least one easy way) to get it to work is to use a virtualenv and install your external project via the requirements.txt file.  Other ways exist, but then you'll need to give more details.

Comment: The console is just a console, it doesn't have the same environment.

Comment: If we're talking about the Python Console, it has the environment of the project interpreter.  If we're talking about the Terminal, then I don't know (never use it).

Comment: So with the correct path added under the project interpreter the console should be able to import my needed scripts then?

Comment: and when I check sys.path I see it there in the console as well.

Comment: and what is even strange when I open a blank console ass opposed to when I run a script and the console comes up it works fine. So the issue is just when I run the script it won't import

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this by adding a new PYTHONPATH and the correct path to the enviroment variable under console in pycharm